# Using "du" command without outputting filepath

Tags: linux, bash, du

So i want to display the filename and the size of the file in MB using the "du" command in my bash script but it outputs the filepath for the file

I have used the command:

```
du -s -BM /home/user/test/test_file_check
```

But my output is:

```
0M      /home/user/test/test_file_check
```

How do i get rid of the `/home/user/test` path from the output?
Would it be possible to use sed to remove the filepath?

Is there alternatively another command better suited for this?

Comment: `du` uses for output the path you provide on the command line. If you want to get relative pathes in the output, write a relativ path on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly tongue in cheek approach. This navigates to the directory and does the `du` in the local directory, then navigates back to the previous location.

```
cd /home/user/test/ && du -s -BM test_file_check && cd - > /dev/null || return
0M      test_file_check
```

Comment: It's also possible to `cd` in subshell without explicit return: `(cd /home/user/test/ && du -s -BM test_file_check)`

Answer (score 0):

Since `sed` does greedy matching by default:

```
du -s -BM /home/user/test/test_file_check | sed 's|/.*/||'
```

`sed` is going to match the longest line that matches `/.*/` (ie, greedy match) and then replace it with nothing (`||`). **NOTE:** since the data includes the `/` character we need a different script delimiter hence the use of `|` as the `sed` script delimiter

Simulating your `du` output:

```
$ echo '0M      /home/user/test/test_file_check' | sed 's|/.*/||'
0M      test_file_check
```